# Voltage and Temperature readout - Order of Magnitude issue

Tags: android, power-management, batterylevel

I'm reading out several values using the `BatteryManager` including voltage

```
int volt = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, -1);
```

The problem is, that some devices return mV and others V (e.g. 5122 and 5).

**Question:** Is there a way to retrieve the order of magnitude or do I have to implement manual plausibility checks?

thanks

Comment: I also faced same problem and got no solution.Finally had to use if else test.Surely if it is 1 to 10 then volt otherwise converted it to volt by dividing 1000

Comment: I did the same as Rasel. It is stupid solution as you lose precision but better than nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO such a "scale" indicator only exists for the battery level (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html) not for the voltage. Usually mV should be returned - but to be on the safe side you will need to do a plausibility check